# Bash function local array variable is not accessible in called place

Tags: linux, bash, shell

There is a 2 bash script file. First file `b.sh` is mentioned below.

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a arr1=()
func() {
    var_a=12
    arr1[0]=20
    arr1[1]=30
    declare -a arr2=()
    arr2[0]=40
    arr2[1]=50
}
```

Second file `a.sh` is mentioned below.

```
#!/bin/bash
source b.sh
func
echo $var_a
echo ${arr1[1]}
echo ${arr2[1]}
```

Output is

```
12
30
```

My doubt is, why the local array variable (`arr2`) in `func` is not accessible in `a.sh`. But the local variable `var_a` is accessible.

Comment: @anubhava The question is about `arr2` and `var_a`.

Comment: @rashok, why do you think `var_a` is a local variable?

Comment: BTW, this question could be simplified. There's no need to have two separate scripts and a `source` command to reproduce this problem -- it could easily be created with just one.

Comment: Ya true, It is a simplified version of the issue faced in an another script based test framework, which constains 2 script file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`arr2` is a local variable because it was created using `declare`. As stated in the [Bash Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#Bash-Builtins):

> When used in a function, `declare` makes each name local, as with the `local` command, unless the `-g` option is used.

Since you didn't create `var_a` with `declare`, the assignment creates a global variable, so it's accessible outside the funtion. If you'd written:

```
declare var_a=12
```

or

```
local var_a=12
```

inside the function then it would have been local.